# Node js CORS. My webapp has stopped working since I have a domain

Tags: ajax, node.js, cors

My node.js webapp was almost ready to go in production but now i have a big problem. Until today, all the tests were done using the browser and the IP address of my vps. Now i have a domain linked to my vps server. From this moment i can't use ajax calls! Chrome's console say:

```
> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
> Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know that CORS regards the access to resources from domain A to  domain B. So maybe, solve this problem by setting some headers to response ojbect is not the best solution, or maybe yes.

I tryed this

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://example.com');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
```

but it works only if i write http://example.com to browser. if i write http://www.example.com, it not work cause origin (http://www.example.com) is different by the origin setted in res object(http://example.com); this is the chrome's cosole error:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://example.com' that  is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

How can i avoid it?? using allow-origin * is not a good solution for my situation but the big problem is:
is this the right way to make it all work ? allowing my domain? o is there something that i am not understanding??

**EDIT**
the problem seems to be unrelated to CORS. After testing, it seems that if you visit by browser www.example.com and, from the client javascript you perform an ajax call to example.com, the request fail (with access control error). It's the same if you visit example.com and you make and ajax call to www.example.com. This is a problem, users must be free to visit my page by typing www.example.com OR example.com. How can resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you just making AJAX calls to you web application? If so, then just omit the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers from your responses so the normal Same Origin Policy rules apply.

Comment: have you tried `*.example.com`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt if i omit the Access-Control-Allow-Origin i can't make ajax calls if the current page is www.example.com. if the current page is example.com , then all works

Comment: Are these ajax calls going to a different domain than the domain hosting the actual web pages?

Comment: @FrederickCheung no but read my last comment!!

Comment: @Radar155: Can you please give us more information about your ajax requests? I understand if you don't want to post the actual domain names, but i think we need more context about your setup and what domain it runs under. Is it running in a sub domain, etc.

Comment: Some code would be useful - it doesn't sound like you should be doing cross origin requests at all

Comment: @FrederickCheung i've just edited my question, if you can read please :)

Comment: Why don't you redirect all users coming to www.example.com to example.com or the other way around? Then you will be able to avoid the whole cors hassle completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess since you haven't posted any code, but it seems like you might be hard-coding absolute URLs in your client-side code.

```
$.get('http://www.example.com/some/url', ...);
```

Don't do this.  Use relative URLs and the browser will automatically make the request to the correct origin.

```
$.get('/some/url', ...);
```

---

On another note, you should not serve the same website from different domains (www.example.com and example.com) as it will hurt SEO.  Instead, pick which should be the canonical domain, and issue permanent (HTTP 301) redirects from the other.